# DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() returns null

Tags: google-apps-script, document

How can I access the active google doc?

```
function test() {
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
Logger.log(doc.getName());
}
```

Logger returns null.
However, there exists an active (opened) document.

Answer (score 3):

This function is currently unsupported and therefore does not work. It should not exist in the documentation and we're addressing the issue.

If you want to interact with a document, use [DocumentApp.openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_documentapp.html#openById) instead. If my document URL is `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1chYJu5ktIeByau-Xtd0XwCYUnMJG32WC7wQe5xMv3TA/edit`, the doc is opened as follows:

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1chYJu5ktIeByau-Xtd0XwCYUnMJG32WC7wQe5xMv3TA');
```

Comment: Hm. What issue will be adressed? The removal of the documentation, or the implementation of the function?
Note:
This feature would enable me to insert my own "templates" into the current document, at the cursor position, e.g a pre-fomatted table.

Comment: We are working on improving the documentation and it will be removed from the docs.

Comment: what is the reason (if any) to withdraw this function? It would be a very nice feature: using my private templates . . .

Comment: In order to use the alternative 'openbyID' I have to know the Gdoc's ID first. How canI put that ID (that is: th ID of the opened (current/avtive) Gdoc in a var?

Answer (score 0):

If, by any chance, what you really want is to get the active sheet (and you're asking for the document as an intermediate step to go off of): you can do that with [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet).